# Object Literals in JavaScript - Where declare correctly Globals and Constants

Tags: javascript, object, literals

using Object Literals in JavaScript, what's the best way to declare **CONSTANTS** and **GLOBALS** within the object itself? (if that's the best way to do it)

For the example below, I need to know, how can I put the `cst_TEST` and `glb_TEST` variables (declared as GLOBAL on the top), inside the `kOBJ` Object? and, in order to be accessible only to `fxAAA()` / `fxBBB()` / `fxCCC()` ;

**Script:**

```
const cst_TEST = {

  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Deacon"

}

var glb_TEST = { age: "30" };

var kOBJ = {

  fxAAA(){ console.log("First Name: " + cst_TEST.firstName); },

  fxBBB(){ console.log("Last Name: " + cst_TEST.lastName); },

  fxCCC(){ console.log("Age: " +glb_TEST.age); },


}
```

**Output:**

```
<script>

  kOBJ.fxAAA(); //output: `First Name: John`

  kOBJ.fxBBB(); //output: `Last Name: Deacon`

  kOBJ.fxCCC(); //output: `Age: 30`

</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)?

Comment: The traditional way is to use a closure so that the globals become local variables inside the closure. With es6 classes you can define private properties

Comment: for this example I need to know (if you can help me), how can I put the `cst_TEST` and `glb_TEST` variables (which are declared as GLOBAL at the top), inside the `kOBJ` Object? and, in order to be accessible only to `fxAAA()` / `fxBBB()` / `fxCCC()` .

Comment: It cannot be "in the _object_" and private to it. Again, a *class* can have private fields, or you use a closure to make them local variables in an inaccessible scope. Do either of these options fit what you're trying to do, and if not, why not?

Comment: answer for what i need:

var kOBJ = {

  glb_TEST: { age: "30" },

  cst_TEST: {

  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Deacon"

  },

  fxAAA(){ console.log("First Name: " + this.cst_TEST.firstName); },

  fxBBB(){ console.log("Last Name: " + this.cst_TEST.lastName); },

  fxCCC(){ console.log("Age: " + this.glb_TEST.age); },


}

Comment: That's not private to the object though. `kOBJ.glb_TEST.age` can be accessed from anywhere.